# Change a label after a specified time

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qpushbutton

I am trying to change a label on a button click and then after 3 seconds I want it to change back to nothing ("")

my code is this:

```
def apply_click(self):
    ui.label_ischanged.setText("Applied!")
```

and I connected it to my button then I used `time.sleep(3)` but I know that it stops the program not in the real time and my button stays pushed for 3 seconds and I got not responding for 3 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like a perfect use case for a QTimer object. The timer will run inside the QT event loop and there is no need to have any additional threads involved.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QMenuBar, QStatusBar
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer

class Interface(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__build_ui()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.setInterval(3000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timer_finished)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.apply_click)

        self.show()

    def apply_click(self):
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            self.label.setText('Timer has been started. Please wait...')
            self.timer.start()

    def timer_finished(self):
        self.label.setText('Time is over')

    def __build_ui(self):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText('Start Timer')
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText('Start Timer')
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.resize(290, 147)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    interface = Interface()
    app.exec()
```